# How to receive the sum of specific rows of a column based on the same category column and time column

Tags: r

Having a dataframe like this:

```
data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2), timespand = c("2020-12","2020-12","2019-06","2020-12","2019-06","2019-06"), c1 = c(0.4,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.5,1.2), c2 = c(2.1,3.4,5.2,1,0.3,0.4))
```

How is it possible to add the values of every different column of c1 and c2 based on the same id and time spand:

Expected output

```
timespand id c1    c2
"2019-06" 1  0.1  5.2
"2019-06" 2  1.7  0.7
"2019-12" 1  0     0
"2019-12" 2  0     0
"2020-06" 1  0     0
"2020-06" 2  0     0
"2020-12" 1  0.6  5.5
"2020-12" 2  0.4  1.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/).  Below are the steps followed:

1. Group by 'id', 'timespand'
2. Get the `sum` of columns that `starts_with` 'c' in [`summarise`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html)
3. Convert the 'timespand' to `Date` class
4. Use [`complete`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/1.1.3/topics/complete) to include the missing combinations by taking the `seq`uence of 'timespand' from `min` to `max` by '6 month'
5. Reconvert the 'timespand' back to the original format and `arrange` the rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(id, timespand) %>%
     summarise(across(starts_with('c'), sum, na.rm = TRUE), 
        .groups = 'drop') %>%
     mutate(timespand = as.Date(as.yearmon(timespand))) %>% 
     complete(id, timespand = seq(min(timespand), max(timespand),
        by = '6 month'), fill = list(c1 = 0, c2 = 0)) %>% 
     mutate(timespand = format(timespand, '%Y-%m')) %>%
     arrange(timespand)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     id timespand    c1    c2
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 2019-06     0.1   5.2
2     2 2019-06     1.7   0.7
3     1 2019-12     0     0  
4     2 2019-12     0     0  
5     1 2020-06     0     0  
6     2 2020-06     0     0  
7     1 2020-12     0.6   5.5
8     2 2020-12     0.4   1
```

---

If we want the `mean` just change the line in `summarise` from `sum` to `mean`

```
df1 %>% 
     group_by(id, timespand) %>%
     summarise(across(starts_with('c'), mean, na.rm = TRUE), 
        .groups = 'drop') %>%
     mutate(timespand = as.Date(as.yearmon(timespand))) %>% 
     complete(id, timespand = seq(min(timespand), max(timespand),
        by = '6 month'), fill = list(c1 = 0, c2 = 0)) %>% 
     mutate(timespand = format(timespand, '%Y-%m')) %>%
     arrange(timespand)
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     id timespand    c1    c2
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 2019-06    0.1   5.2 
2     2 2019-06    0.85  0.35
3     1 2019-12    0     0   
4     2 2019-12    0     0   
5     1 2020-06    0     0   
6     2 2020-06    0     0   
7     1 2020-12    0.3   2.75
8     2 2020-12    0.4   1
```

Comment: Thank you. One question more. Is it possible to receive also as and alternative the sum/nrow result of the specific category results? Example for 2019-06 id 2 1.7/2=0.85 result

Comment: @ErikBodg You meant the `mean` instead of `sum`.  So, just change the `sum` function in `summarise` to `mean`

Comment: @ErikBodg can you just change the line to `summarise(across(starts_with('c'), mean, na.rm = TRUE), 
        .groups = 'drop')`